# How to delete a file if it exists?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I delete a file if exists in a directory with python 2.7 using `os / app`?

I've tried with

```
os.remove('directory/file.png')
```

but if the item doesn't exist, I've got an error.

Comment: can't you just ignore the error?

Comment: Me yes, users no, I've fixed my problem with  except OSError or NameError:

Comment: `NameError`? Why would you get a `NameError`? That'd indicate you're using a nonexistent variable, which would indicate a bug in your code.

Comment: By "ignore the error", pqnet probably means using a try-except to catch the error and not do anything in the except block.

Comment: yes, i meant catching OSError and ignoring the exception (as  user2357112 answer below suggests) following the python EAFP philosophy http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp

Answer (score 11):

```
try:
    os.remove(path)
except OSError:
    pass
```

Just catch the error and ignore it. (Ignoring errors isn't something you'd do for all errors, but here, it's what you want.)

Any approach based on checking the file's existence in advance would be prone to race conditions. To avoid race conditions, the existence check has to be part of the removal operation, and this is how you do that in Python.

Comment: Note that, as python documentation suggests (http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.remove) `os.remove` can raise an `OSError` exception if the path is a directory (or for any other reason the file could not be deleted), which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 5):

```
if os.path.exists(path):
    os.remove(path)
```

Comment: That is discuraged, see below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18523832/how-to-delete-a-file-if-it-exists#comment27241501_18523884

Answer (score 0):

Check if it exists first:

```
if os.path.exists(path):
    os.remove(path)
```

Comment: this is discouraged because the file could be removed (for example, by another process) between the check and the actual removal, so in a race condition an exception would be thrown and left uncaught

Comment: @pqnet But that's a very theoretical situation unless you are doing massive parallelism etc.

Comment: since a more safe try/except pattern exists (and is the encouraged pattern to be used in python) i want to deprecate this one. Also, the fact that the OP doesn't know beforehands if the file is there or not suggests that it could disappear in any moment

Answer (score 0):

use exception:

```
try:
    os.remove("file_name")
except:
    return "something went wrong"
```